# defining structure variable during declaration

Tags: c, structure, declaration

I have been trying something in structures in C.

```
struct val{
    unsigned int a : 1 ;
}store[100] ;
```

Now I want to initialize all the array members value to 1. That is, I want  all the array members to have their variable `a` assigned to 1. I can use a loop for that but how can I do this during the declaration?

```
struct val
{
    unsigned int a=1 : 1 ;
}store[100];
```

How can i achieve this? The above syntax is coming out to be wrong in code::blocks.

Comment: if you have this in a class you can initialize it in the constructor, by using a simple for with 100 runs and initialize every element

Comment: @MartinWalzl, he's working with C, not C++

Comment: It's tagged C, not C++.

Comment: actually 100 is a test number, the actual number is of 9 digits. So as you can see i can't use a for.

Comment: oh crap sry, i think i just overread that....

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> struct val
> {
> unsigned int a : 1;
> }store[100];
> ```

I initially thought that what you were doing was a bitfield initialization. [Further research though suggested I am wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1601288/1426969), and that you are trying to use gcc's [designated initializers](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html). [What you want to do, is not possible that way.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13706809/structs-in-c-with-initial-values) I found another way in your code that you can do it, though:

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned int a;
} val;
```

then, where you want to initialize the array, you will do something like that:

```
val values[100] = {[0].a = 1};
```

This works by exploiting this behavior of gcc:

> If the same field is initialized multiple times, it has the value from the last initialization. If any such overridden initialization has side-effect, it is unspecified whether the side-effect happens or not. Currently, GCC discards them and issues a warning.

My Test Program follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct val {
    unsigned int a;
};



int
main (void)
{
    struct val value[100] = {[0].a = 1};
    printf ("A random val's value is %d\n", value[40].a);
    return 0;
}
```

Compiles and works cleanly on my GCC 4.9.1.

Comment: the loop is a good solution but only for small numbers. I will have to run the loop a billion times if i want to initialize every array member in my code. So for loop can't be used.

Comment: @KapilGarg I edited the answer. See if the changes reflect what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible.

You can use a loop, or, if by any chance you want to initialize *all* struct's data members to a specific value, you can also use `memset`:

```
struct val {
    unsigned int a : 1 ;
} store[N];

memset(store, value, N * sizeof(struct val));
```

Comment: ok, but what is we have `unsigned int a : 10;`. What will happen after `memset()`?

Comment: I think it depends on the value being set, but appropriate bits should be set the same way as they are defined in a value. Which makes it risky with non-zero value. Unless you know what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

Before declaring a `struct` variable you can't initialize its member. Initialization can be done as

```
struct val{
    unsigned int a : 1;
}store[100] = {[0].a = 1} ; // Designated initializer
```

but it will initialize `a` member of other elements of `store` to `0`. To initialize member `a` of all elements of `store` you need a loop.